# BadSqlGrammarException in Spring jdbc template

Tags: java, sql, spring, postgresql, jdbc

I am using Jdbctemplate to retrieve a single record from the db.here is the method.

```
public Advocate queryPrimaryDetails(String regCaseType, String regNo, String regYear) throws SQLException {
        String sql = "select pet_adv,pet_adv_cd from civil_t where regcase_type=? and reg_no=? and reg_year=?";
        Advocate list = (Advocate) getJdbcTemplate().queryForObject(sql, new Object[]{Integer.valueOf(regCaseType),Integer.valueOf(regNo),Integer.valueOf(regYear)},new RowMapper<Object>() {
            public Object mapRow(ResultSet resultSet, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                return resultSet.next() ? new Advocate(resultSet.getInt("pet_adv_cd"), resultSet.getString("pet_adv"))
                        : null;
            }
        });
        System.out.println(list);
        return list;
    }
```

In my scenario, it is completely possible to NOT get a hit on my query so my question is how do I get around the following error message.

HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [select pet_adv,pet_adv_cd from civil_t where regcase_type=?]; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "civil_t" does not exist

Comment: Try using double qoutes around the table name `select pet_adv,pet_adv_cd from "civil_t" ... ` or with the database name `select pet_adv,pet_adv_cd from database.civil_t ... `

Comment: All other tables in the same database are executed successfully along with this query when I try to execute in query builder it works. the problem is not with the query.

Comment: Prefix the database name before the table did not work out.

Answer (score 0):

The exception is raised from the underlying postgresql JDBC-driver, because the table **civil_t** is not found in the database you're connecting to.

Comment: Only the query has been executed in query builder it works.

Comment: either you are not connecting to the non-existence of DB or table does not exist in DB.